# Classes and object issues in Java

Tags: java, class, object

I have certain issue. while I do understand the reason code returns "Nothing" and 24.0 I can't quite grasp why I'm getting: "Nothing" 24.0 AND 9.0. Can someone please explain the issue better? Thank you, here is the code.

```
class Object {

    int w; int h; int d;

    void test() { System.out.print("araferi ");}

    double volum() {return w*h*d;}

    void volum(double x) {

    System.out.print(" "+ --x);}

 }


 public class Test {

    public static void main (String[] args){

       Object ob1=new Object();

       ob1.w=2;

       ob1.h=3;

       ob1.d=4;

       ob1.test();

       ob1.volum(10);

       System.out.print(" "+ob1.volum());
    }

 }
```

Comment: change class name `Object` to `ObjectTest` because Object class is reserved class by Java

Answer (score 0):

The `9.0` output comes from this line:

```
ob1.volum(10);
```

which receives `10` as argument, but in the body of the method it's being decreased (`--x`), that's why you get `9`.

**Note:** Don't use `Object` as the name of a class, since it's [the root of the class hierarchy in Java.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) Change it to something else, like `MyObject`.

Comment: He's not specifically printing the result of the volum method for the value of 9 as his function doesn't return a result but it does print out the value

Answer (score 0):

The line `ob1.volum(10);` calls the second `volum` method, which decrements then prints its argument.  That's what's showing you `9.0`.

Answer (score 0):

The function:

```
void volum(double x) {
    System.out.print(" "+ --x);}
}
```

Will print out  a value of 9 as you've applied a pre-decrement to the value you passed in (10)